# Move RewriteBase from htaccess to site conf doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

This is my original .htaccess file. The rewrite rule works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /backenddev/
RewriteRule ^share/([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz123456789]{8})$ share.php?token=$1
```

But after moving the `RewriteBase` part into Apache's site conf file and restart Apache, it doesn't work anymore.

The new .htaccess file with the rewrite rule only:

```
RewriteRule ^share/([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz123456789]{8})$ share.php?token=$1
```

And the Apache site conf file:

```
  Alias /backenddev "/var/www/backend_dev/"
  <Directory /var/www/backend_dev/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase "/backenddev/"
    AllowOverride All
    
    ...
  </Directory>
```

When I open the URL `https://<mysite>/backenddev/share/XV6TqNpE` I get an 404 and the site content is:

```
The requested URL /var/www/<mysite>/backend_dev/share.php was not found on this server.
```

A redirection to `https://<mysite>/backenddev/share.php?token=XV6TqNpE` is expected.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why did you move just the `RewriteBase` directive into the `<Directory>` container in the server config? Have you also removed the `RewriteEngine` directive from the `.htaccess` file? What is the document root? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? What is your file structure?

Comment: If `share.php` resided in same directory where this .htaccess is then `RewriteBase` isn't even needed.

Comment: @MrWhite I have two directories _backend_ and _backenddev_ which shares the same Git repository. I also want to put the .htaccess file in to the repository. So it would by nice if _backend_ and _backenddev_ can share the same .htaccess file and only the differences get configured in the sites conf.
`RewriteEngine` is removed too from .htaccess file, yes.
The .htaccess file is in the document root besides of the share.php.

Comment: @anubhava yes, `share.php` and `.htaccess` are both in the document root. But there are other rules pointing to non document root files, e. g. `RewriteRule ^match\.php$ api/match/match.php [L]`.
Removing `RewriteBase` from .htaccess site conf have the same result 404.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^match\.php$ api/match/match.php [L]` should not make difference on the rule you've shown above. I believe `ap/` is a sub-directory in `DocumentRoot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `RewriteBase` directive defined in parent configs is not *inherited* by child configs by default<sup>***1**</sup>. You need to explicitly enable this with the `MergeBase` option in the parent config.

For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/backend_dev/>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /backenddev/
  RewriteOptions MergeBase
  AllowOverride All  
  ...
</Directory>
```

Note that child configs can still override this by setting there own `RewriteBase`.

<sup>***1**</sup> This *default* behaviour actually changed in Apache 2.4.4. Between 2.4.0 and 2.4.3 the value of the `RewriteBase` was apparently merged into child configs by default.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

> **MergeBase**
> With this option, the value of RewriteBase is copied from where it's explicitly defined into any sub-directory or sub-location that doesn't define its own RewriteBase. This was the default behavior in 2.4.0 through 2.4.3, and the flag to restore it is available Apache HTTP Server 2.4.4 and later.

Note, however, that this option alone does not enable mod_rewrite *inheritance*. Directives in the child (`.htaccess`) configs will still completely override directives in the parent `<Directory>` container. The `MergeBase` option refers only to the value of `RewriteBase`.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^share/([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz123456789]{8})$ share.php?token=$1
> ```

This could be "simplified" to:

```
RewriteRule ^share/([a-np-z1-9]{8})$ share.php?token=$1 [NC]
```

Since only the `o`, `O` and `0` are omitted from the character *ranges*.

The `NC` flag would then be required to match the corresponding uppercase letters.

Also, consider adding the `L` flag since you have "other rules" - and these will likely be unnecessarily processed (assuming there is no conflict already).

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. With `RewriteOptions MergeBase` it works like charm.
Also thank you for the shorter regex! It is more readable than the explicit one.

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed you edited/appended the trailing slash on the `RewriteBase` directive - this trailing slash is entirely optional. The Apache docs seem to be a bit inconsistent in this regard, some examples include the trailing slash, some omit it. But behaviour with or without is identical.

Comment: However, whilst on the subject of trailing slashes... your use of the `Alias` directive is not strictly correct, as you've omitted the trailing slash on the _URL-path_ (1st arg), but included the trailing slash on the _file-path_ (2nd arg). Although I expect this is working OK for you (and in my tests there is no discernable difference - I expect the OS is quietly resolving away any double slash that results in the filesystem path). However, in this case, the docs do explicitly state: "if you omit the slash on the _URL-path_ then you must also omit it from the _file-path_".

Comment: Thank you! I'am sorry for editing your config because I expected that is only working with the trailing slash. But I can confirm that it works with and without. Thank you for clarify!